# how to convert columns into rows in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called reviewdb with columns q1,q2,q2.I want to find average of q1,q2 and q3 and store those average values in rows. please help me.

```html
q1 q2 q3
5  4  2
4  3  2
4  5  1

find avg of q1,q2, q3 and store avg of q1 in a row and avg of q2 in another row and avg of q3 in the next row.
q  average
q1  4.3
q2  4
q3  1.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a simple `union all`:

```
select 'q1' as q, avg(q1) as average from t
union all
select 'q2' as q, avg(q2) as average from t
union all
select 'q3' as q, avg(q3) as average from t;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 'q1' as q, avg(q1) avrg from yourtable

union all  

select 'q2', avg(q2) from yourtable

union all 

select 'q3', avg (q3) from yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select q 
      ,AVG(CAST(Vals AS DECIMAL(10,2))) Average
from tableName  
  UNPIVOT (vals for q in (q1,q2,q3))up
Group by q
```

or to get two decimal places

```
Select q 
      ,CAST(AVG(CAST(Vals AS DECIMAL(10,2)) )AS DECIMAL(10,2)) Average
from @t 
  UNPIVOT (vals for q in (q1,q2,q3))up
Group by q
```